# How many bytes of memory does weights need?

Tags: python, memory, tensorflow

I am writing this piece of code to calculate the memory taken by `weights`in bytes:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import sys

n_input = 784  # MNIST data input (img shape: 28*28)
n_classes = 10  # MNIST total classes (0-9 digits)
# Weights & bias
weights = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_input, n_classes]))
bias = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_classes]))


model = tf.global_variables_initializer()
with tf.Session() as session:
session.run(model)
print(session.run(weights))

print(sys.getsizeof(session.run(weights)))
#31472
```

That doesn't seem to help in finding out the size of `weights`.
Can someone please suggest the correct approach?

Thanks.

Comment: That seems correct to me,  `784 * 10 * 4 = 31,360` (shape * 4 since default type is float). Probably with 112 byte overhead. So it gives you 31,472 byte. What else do you want to get?

Comment: This is how many bytes does `tf.float32` take. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format
As this link shown, `tf.float32` takes `32 bits` which means that takes `4 bytes`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the amount of bytes you get is correct. The weights is a matrix of 784 by 10. Each value consists of four bytes. This gives you 784*10*4=31360 bytes. Sys says that it is 31472 - 31360 = 112 bytes more. This looks like a nice overhead (28 4 byte values) to me!

Let us know if you have more questions!